# default_url_option lost for Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have set default_url_option for I18n in the ApplicationController, which works well for all controllers except for Devise. I lost the :locale option after redirect using authenticate_user! method from Devise.

How to enable this for devise?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any resolution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No luck, I tried to write my own authenticate_user methods

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for this ?